# Passing variable from app.js to ejs file into a script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to pass variable which is defined in app.js into a script tag inside and ejs file.
So the app.js in short looks like this:

```
//app.js
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var request = require("request")



var thelist =[]
app.locals.myVar = thelist.length;

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("search")
})

app.get("/show/:id", function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    thelist.push(id)
    console.log(thelist);
    res.redirect('/')
});
```

The variable I want to pass is the app.locals.myVar, acutally this method doesnt work and I still get that myVar is not defined in ejs file

The ejs file is here:

```
//search.ejs
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MYMDB</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/app.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>


    <a id="show-data" href="/data" class="ui right floated disabled button"> 
      See the table 
    </a>



  <script>
    $('#run').click(function() {
      $('#show-data').removeClass('ui disabled button');
      $('#show-data').addClass('ui loading button');
      setTimeout(function () {      
          $('#show-data').removeClass("ui loading button");
          $('#show-data').addClass('ui basic button')
              }, myVar*2000);
   });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see im trying to use myVar- the variable that is obtained on the server side js and then using it in the client side js. But it appears to not be recognized in the ejs file.

Comment: `res.render()` is parameterized.  So, try `res.render("search", {some:"var"});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res.render()` is parameterized.  So, try:

```
res.render("search", {
    myVar: "value"
});
```

See Express docs for: [`app.render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.render) and [`res.render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render).

Your HTML should look something like this with the `<%= myVar %>` included.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <script>
        // Print out the variable I got
        console.log(<%= myVar %>)
        // or
        console.log("<%= myVar %>")
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: should I keep myvar as in app.locale or just define it globally in app.js?

Comment: I advocate dependency injection, so I would set it explicitly through the object you hand to `res.render()`.

Comment: so like this ? `res.render("search", {
    some: thelist.length
});`

Comment: @AlexT, yes.  That would be a way to do it.

Comment: I tried this and I console.logged it inside script tag of the ejs file but it says its undefined

Comment: @AlexT Are you telling the template the your variable should be evaluated with `<%= myVar %>`?

Answer (score 1):

So the general way of doing this is when you render a template pass in a data/object structure with all the data your template needs as follows:

```
//
// Pass all your objects, globals as references in your server side 
// code/endpoint, below i have also passed a library moment js so i
// can use that server side in my template for dates
// 
var data = {name: "Hello World", age:32, local: app.local, moment:moment}
```

Then when you render your template pass in the data structure

```
res.render("template", data);
```

In your template

```
<h1><%=name=></h1>
<h2><%=age%>
<script>
  var scope = <%=data.local%>
</script>
```

Or even better pass it as an element attribute (safer as it's passed as a string and decoded using JSON.parse.

```
<body id="body" data-server-scope="<%=data.local%>">

<Script>var scope = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("body").attr("data-server-scope"));</script>
```

Either solution will pass the server data (scope) down to your js client, ihave passed data.local, you could call this data.client or you could just pass down all the data structure, but in my example i have a reference to moment which can only be used within the template, it can't be passed down magically to the client, in-case you are wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you pass data from controller to template ejs and want to use them inside script , There is two different things happen if send data is string then you normally do ,

res.render("template", {data: {name: 'name',permission: {id: 1, name: 'test'}} );

```
<script>
  var scope = "<%=name%>"
</script>
```

If you send object data then you must use string literals ,

``